# Using function as an attribute for div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

Since my selector options and logo images have the same names i want to use this to make a function that changes the image when you select. I've tried this:

```
$(function(){
  $(selector).click(
    $(function(){
      $(div).attr("src", "($(selector).val()).png")
}))})
```

Buuut, no sauce :(

With help from parth718 got to this:

```
$(function)(){
$(selector).click($(div).attr("src", "images/logos/"+($(selector).val()+".png")))};
```

But now i'm getting error: TypeError: g.handler.apply is not a function.
I'm running jQuery 1.12.2 from Google's CDN on this.
Toughts? .-.

Comment: Try this - `$(logodiv).attr("src", $(pagamento).val()+".png")`

Comment: You don't need to define a second document ready handler *inside* your click handler.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, "$file.png" gives you the result you want, not in javascript ...

You have to concatenate strings with your var with the plus operator.

As said, you have to do a :

`$(logodiv).attr("src", $(selector).val()+".png")`

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$(logodiv).attr("src", "($(selector).val()).png");
```

try this

```
$(logodiv).attr("src",($(selector).val()+".png");
```

You are using variable inside "" therefore the attr will be changed as

```
src="$(selector).val().png"
```

exact string will be there and not the selector variable.

Comment: The attribute setting worked but i still can't run the function on click, 
$(function)(){$(sel).click($(div).attr("src", "images/logos/"+($(sel).val()+".png")))};
When i try to select the console returns "TypeError: g.handler.apply is not a function". Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that you need to make a new function like that.... Use the normal way i.e. Function myFuntion(){your code}.... And if my answer worked please mark so that i can get reputations 